# How to stop password reset link being leaked to third party sites

Tags: security, deployment, content-security-policy, websecurity, devsecops

everyone when i open the password reset link I noticed that it is being leaked to third party CSP reporting sites like bam.nr-data.net, linkedin, facebook.

To prevent if someone clicks on third party site rel="noreferrer" is added but the password reset link is sent automatically to other sites.